# Probability Mass Function of having both loaded & fair coins

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables

Suppose a box contains many coins that are either biased (loaded) or balanced. **A loaded coin has probability of landing on its head as p ∈ (0.5, 1.0)**, and a balanced coin, of course has probability 0.5 of its head.

Suppose we pick one coin from a box and toss it for n times. Let's say the proportion of balanced coin in the box is b, and loaded coin, (1-b). **Then, what would be our probability mass function of having heads (defined as X)??**

I assume we can simply get pmf by adding the two conditional probabilities:
P (X | choosing balanced coin) + P (X | choosing loaded coin). Of course, P (X | choosing balanced coin) would simply be binomial pmf. **My question is, how are we going to define pmf for the number of heads of loaded coin flip?

Comment: The pmf for a loaded coin is also binomial, just different probability of "success."

Comment: Here the probability of landing on its head for a loaded coin is not definite, it can be any number between 0.5 and 1.0. Does it still yield same pmf as the pmf of balanced coin?

Comment: If $p$ is **fixed** but unknown, the distribution of the number of heads is binomial, not the same binomial as a balanced coin, but same family. If $p$ is a *random variable*, things change, but from the wording of the question it looks as if $p$ is fixed but unknown. If they wanted to consider $p$ to be a random variable, its distribution should have been specified.

Comment: Thanks. What if p is r.v. following uniform distribution from 0.5 to 1?

Comment: You may want to ask that separately, without the distraction of the fair coins. One gets a somewhat unattractive but relatively standard integral.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose you get a loaded coin. If you flip it $n$ times, then you have $n$ independent trials with probability $p$ of success (getting a head). Thus, the number of heads using a loaded coin follows a binomial distribution with parameters $n,p$.

To calculate the pmf of $X$, we have
\begin{align*}
P(X = k) &= P(X = k, F = 1)+P(X = k,F = 0) \\
&= P(X =k|F = 1)P(F = 1)+P(X = k|F = 0)P(F=0)
\end{align*}
where $F$ is the event (indicator) that you chose a fair coin.

Comment: So it should be the sum of joint pmfs. Thank you! What would be a specific pmf of number of heads when flipping loaded coin, then? Here the probability p of landing a head is not definite, it is any number between 0.5 and 1.0. If we suppose p is uniformly distributed from 0.5 and 1.0, how we incorporate this to our binomial pmf?

Comment: The problem implies that $p$ is fixed, not uniformly distributed. I explained the distribution of such a coin in the first paragraph. Please consider giving a [check mark $\checkmark$](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). Thanks.